# Get user and list of products from a data frame of users and products in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns Users and Products.

```
> head(df1)
     Users         Product Code   
[1,] "Alice"        "Soap"   
[2,] "Alice"        "Shampoo"   
[3,] "Alice"        "Toothpaste"
[4,] "Bob"          "Cup"   
[5,] "Bob"          "Spoon"    
[6,] "Charlie"      "Towel"
```

Is it possible to change this to

```
> head(df1)
  Users         Product Code   
[1,] "Alice"   "Soap, Shampoo, Toothpaste"   
[2,] "Bob"     "Cup, Spoon"   
[3,] "Charlie" "Towel"
```

using any direct simple commands.

I currently do this by taking each user and checking what products he bought. Is there any simple way to do this?

```
item_set = list()
for(user_id in 1:length(user_code))
{
  item_set[[user_id]] = products$product_code[products$customerID == user_id]
}
```

Comment: It seems like you have a `matrix` instead of `data.frame`.  If it is a data.frame, you can do `aggregate(Product_Code ~Users, df1, FUN = toString)`

Comment: It worked, thanks!! I was storing the output in a matrix but the input is in a data.frame